# ~__nat() deleted error in ThreadPool implementation

Tags: c++, multithreading, clang, threadpool, move-semantics

I am trying to implement a ThreadPool,but the clang compiler is giving me an error, which I do not know how to fix. My ThreadPool consists of 1 thread for planning and adding tasks to the queue (Scheduler), 1 thread for taking the tasks out of the queue and assigning separate threads to them(Executor), and child threads for each task. The problem arises in the Executor section:

```
struct Executor {
    std::shared_ptr<SharedData> data_ptr_;

    // constructor
    explicit Executor (std::shared_ptr<SharedData>& data_ptr):
      data_ptr_ (data_ptr)
    {}


    // methods
    void execute () {
      while (true) {
        auto cur_task = data_ptr_ -> queue_.Take();
        if (cur_task == std::nullopt) break;
        std::thread child_thread {&Executor::executeChild, this, std::move(cur_task)};
        // ...
      }

      // join child threads here
    }

    void executeChild (Task task) {
      // ...
      task();
      // ...
    }

  };
```

The compiler does not like this line:
`std::thread child_thread {&Executor::executeChild, this, std::move(cur_task)};`

The error message that it produces is incomprehensible to me :(
`In template: attempt to use a deleted function error occurred here in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::__thread_execute<std::unique_ptr<std::__thread_struct>, void (tp::Executor::*)(fu2::detail::function<fu2::detail::config<true, false, fu2::capacity_default>, fu2::detail::proper... in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::__thread_proxy<std::tuple<std::unique_ptr<std::__thread_struct>, void (tp::Executor::*)(fu2::detail::function<fu2::detail::config<true, false, fu2::capacity_default>, fu2::detai... in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::thread::thread<void (tp::Executor::*)(fu2::detail::function<fu2::detail::config<true, false, fu2::capacity_default>, fu2::detail::property<true, false, void ()>>), tp::Executor ... '~__nat' has been explicitly marked deleted here`

Are there any errors in my code? What is the compiler saying?

Comment: It seems, `cur_task` is a `std::optional<Task>`. Hence, you pass a `std::optional` to `executeChild`, but `executeChild` is expecting as `Task`. Does `std::thread child_thread {&Executor::executeChild, this, std::move(*cur_task)};` fix the problem (note the `*` in the `move`)? Otherwise, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Sedenion WOW, it does. I learned about std::optional just today, so I did not know that I have to indirect it to get the stored value. Thank you!

Comment: I posted a full answer, feel free to accept it.

Comment: FYI: The class that you have created is _not_ a thread pool. Your class creates a new thread for each task that it is given. The entire purpose of a thread pool is to avoid doing exactly that. A thread pool _re-uses_ its worker threads. Each worker thread waits for a task to be given, and when it gets a task, it performs it, and then it goes back to waiting for the next task. The same is true of any xxxxx pool that you may hear of: The purpose is to re-use xxxxx objects instead of continually creating and destroying them.

Comment: @SolomonSlow Yes, now I see the problem. Should I keep an unordered_set for threads that do not have a task assigned or are there more elegant solutions?

Comment: In a typical thread-pool, the task queue is a multi-consumer blocking queue, and the worker threads compete with each other to take tasks from the queue. Whenever the queue is empty, the "take" function blocks its caller. In a _simplistic_ thread pool, that's pretty much all there is to it. In a more sophisticated pool, there might be a manager thread or function that can ask workers to do "special" things by submitting special tasks. (E.g., if demand decreases, a manager thread might kill off some workers by submitting a few tasks that throw some exception that a worker handles by exiting.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue that `cur_task` is a `std::optional<Task>` and you pass this `std::optional<Task>` directly to `executeChild()`. But `executeChild()` expects not a `std::optional<Task>` but a `Task`. Since you check if the optional is `nullopt` before creating the thread, you probably want to use

```
std::thread child_thread {&Executor::executeChild, this, std::move(*cur_task)};
```

The `*` in front of `cur_task` is [`operator*`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/operator*), which assumes that the optional contains a value and returns a reference to the contained value (if it doesn't, you have undefined behavior). Note there is also [`std::optional::value()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/value) which throws if the optional is empty.

Reproducible example: The following code was adapted from your code, and shows the `'~__nat' has been explicitly marked deleted here` error with clang 14 and libc++ ([example on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGISQCspK4AMngMmAByPgBGmMQgZkEADqgKhE4MHt6%2B/ilpGQJhEdEscQlJtpj2jgJCBEzEBNk%2BfoFVNZn1jQTFUbHxiUEKDU0tue0jPX2l5UMAlLaoXsTI7BzmAMzhyN5YANQmm25sLCQAnkfYJhoAgls7e5iHxwQIxJhM6Fc392bbDF2XgORw8yVqzFoPzuvxGxC8Dn2ABUmAoANYmADsVju%2Bzx%2BwAbqg8Oh9qhkvEmERiBB5rSsVZMQARX5YlmbHH3O5whEEfZCBCNTDoJlUpgM374/YjdAgEDkiFiUEo9FXZFMNGYWmHbH7D4EFYMHWM9kWHUsmHMo6c2EEeGI7CqTDILzU42S/EyuUKQUfdAAfXBxFBAqFIrFavQYsDdv91tZuPxAHok/s0AweQ4SB68ZhVMlaHhkIR9o7na6SPsIF6QD6wzHg8dQ37RQ0fmYAGz7KMNBvzEA5/E9pgN/1V4d9wcSq0wxN4lP7NhvDAKQdEkn7PPlgjPbUSuf4gDuCDou7tXkw83dB6lTAraZW/oa6JeTO70aDY4AtGqUZr6Ry%2BwLgAjheF7%2BgAdH%2BWrzPGN74ngVBVi6xBPqiaKvkcb41gwXi0LQCpXjEHwanBtxSlKNZvCRpLICetABtRnykhKnZli61JyluHGYG49HoKQ%2BxvHgCiCTWZwElqKFoeisFWhyg5SguEEqYp5oJuRFELtoxJGnRdCkkxXwKPsCDxJgU4zlyml4uupLca6vH8VWKoYc%2BaJXvuNnJqmKkQWp7kAZyFFAb5qkHmyrLyWavwcIstCcAEvB%2BBwWikKgnBuNY1jSssqzPFsPCkAQmhxYsaKJJsEEBJIkgAJwBJsXCbBoZhcJidWbPonCSMlpXpZwvAKCAGjFaVixwLAMCICgqAsMkp5kBQEBoPNi0oAYRhSBoo00LQO7EMNEAxP1MThI05ycEVq1sIIADyDC0JdqW8FgLCGMA4gvaQ%2BAfA4eCScN30OTuV28OEO4Jd9hbERdHhYP1dp4CwYOLFQBjAAoABqeCYIed0UilRX8IIIhiOwUgyIIigqOo326Fw%2BgfSg2WWPoeAxMNkCLAqmRA1%2BMpYaYljWO1%2BwCwQ6Aw1hMPC1YlhDdUzoQi4DDuJ4rR6KE4T9GUgyM6k6QQuMfgGwUEIzAMCSM3YytdKMzQa7kNtK/9dQO5bevW7YDsm3oUxNJ7cxcIsCh5Wseh2pg6w8PFiV9d9GUcKoAAcHZfh2khpptwD7FIEEaAXVZZSLbOlvgbqFYJHhrfQxCHP8Ie8CVL3zOViQdhBdV1ZiKeSJi7UBFwHadp23UcL1pAowEo0pWlSdDSNY2t6Qk0zcsBDJK65CUKtC115ErDrKn6eZ9nH155IBcF7wwqECQJJ6CTwiiOIlPPzTaj9QzpCHsQTDJFRuPJKpA568CTndV0W8%2BSoCQifDOWddgX3zoXDQxc5r73iA3Jq8xm7jUWGZL4gxaTj0ntPWe/UF62CXi3LQbdSAVWHhBSQHZtr9wCCnLgSQAiYiCFDTYCd56DWXnQ1e0014QCQHvRaO8VoYPWkgrakgdp8DoAdI6J1vpnWYMQZ6105q3QIA9J6/U3ofS%2BmlX6dtAb9RBjHcGghqj9Rhv/XR8N1hpSRijbgcU%2BAY2xrjfGhMwZUxfuTCQ0gP5KC/vTRITMjAs1LjYGGXMSG8wEPzQWmwmRy1FpiRWnRnAQFcH7Rm2sShWz0IbQoWQnam1INUi2OtZj6w6Hbd2PRSltLdgwbogdmmVJtr7Op/sPYDK9hIUO4cKbFQ%2BPYuOHAQFgIGsnNOCDz5GEvtfNBEAS7yxsOXe%2B9cq77Brpg45/wzC4JEWVUghCsAJBIRVMwmJmG1U6hobu3cuB90xKQ3g5DQGUOEcNUatDfESKQBvaBsjpEHyPpweBZ9FG5xQTfYIFcH6ykZs/Mmb9ImyE/nTNKugzC/3/oAnxCylnAo4JAzeroyRwLWcinOWzUHoNrlgrYVy8GtwIcxYhCyyEgBnkCxOIKaH4IYYkMwEEWqbE2HVDsNU2ocK4WS/hgjwHCPBRNcR4ipHyLrrC41gxgBcJxWo%2BIGjTrnV0SEm6jAjGPWepYzA70jAWNengP6jgbHAydDxEJEMnHQw5q4847jEbEGRkA9GTBMY4zxgTRgITcWvwpgS6m0TiU6BAF1HOiT9ns05vAHm4I%2BacAlt8bJuTLDtQKe0vwxS1ZdPKbrYODTzaZC6Y0zIQdWm2x6X0x2OR6nDohKOwd3sA5js1kM6Y4zg5TJWBHRmUd5nAO1SspFWdgDIGQHnOVXBi6swObgI52DGanLNRcxV1y9UCqIY89uLzmE/M6u8jsPcU51UZlDEVYrllUNBTc/V8BJHyigdvZacL4iHzYIill%2B7D3HogkVO%2B1JH44tkHirNoSiXfwLeSgBQCoY0olXSmDMDmWn1Q0erhGHOXnOwZsR90r7lCv%2BVPUVFCqOLzBdKxhndJCbDapiSTHCe6bGUYWzgAjxVCI4Hy0REjDWzS5UtXed6QAEmQMkZI/oCRcDqv6AwO4Rj%2BlUJnVR%2B0bWUE0WlbRF1HUGOdcYt1r0PXmI8T6v1ANMBAzSnYkNjioZpRcXDDAfnZlxqpX4xNASU3BJ8aE/DETCO5uI9IIt9bkkc1SRWiEQMkxeny427pKtW3q3HVrNWM6qk9oEH25rDBGsu0Kb04ZdXOvNuncuodPWF0%2ByXRUiZIclhrpmZu8j8clM6uTmfFgCh9OElMxBCzQW%2BS7PPYJS9ldG7VzvdgyQHH%2BV3MFa%2BmVbUIJJBThoDsvcuAaACEkDQAGeoAr4wtlZgnwNiMg1CmjpqtOIePst1bR6TN1U21Sbbt9MWxuxelzNmWom0xy6Rylsdt2/YgTRpl%2BwbNZxW2tmHcPLM7bOYtU7526HPoeZQYV33gO0v%2B0%2Bm7XA7scMe891773PscEUyB3V0qoZmB3VQznklDqZH8EAA%3D%3D))

```
#include <memory>
#include <thread>
#include <optional>

struct Task{
    void operator()(){}
};

struct SharedData{
    std::optional<Task> Take() { return {}; }
};

struct Executor {
    std::shared_ptr<SharedData> data_ptr_;

    // constructor
    explicit Executor (std::shared_ptr<SharedData>& data_ptr):
      data_ptr_ (data_ptr)
    {}

    // methods
    void execute () {
      while (true) {
        auto cur_task = data_ptr_ -> Take();
        if (cur_task == std::nullopt) break;
        // Mistake in the following line: Need to use *cur_task
        std::thread child_thread {&Executor::executeChild, this, std::move(cur_task)};
        // ...
      }

      // join child threads here
    }

    void executeChild (Task task) {
      // ...
      task();
      // ...
    }
};
```

Error:

```
In file included from <source>:2:
/opt/compiler-explorer/clang-14.0.0/bin/../include/c++/v1/thread:282:5: error: attempt to use a deleted function
    _VSTD::__invoke(_VSTD::move(_VSTD::get<1>(__t)), _VSTD::move(_VSTD::get<_Indices>(__t))...);
    ^
/opt/compiler-explorer/clang-14.0.0/bin/../include/c++/v1/__config:826:15: note: expanded from macro '_VSTD'
#define _VSTD std
              ^
/opt/compiler-explorer/clang-14.0.0/bin/../include/c++/v1/thread:293:12: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::__thread_execute<std::unique_ptr<std::__thread_struct>, void (Executor::*)(Task), Executor *, std::optional<Task>, 2UL, 3UL>' requested here
    _VSTD::__thread_execute(*__p.get(), _Index());
           ^
/opt/compiler-explorer/clang-14.0.0/bin/../include/c++/v1/thread:309:54: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::__thread_proxy<std::tuple<std::unique_ptr<std::__thread_struct>, void (Executor::*)(Task), Executor *, std::optional<Task>>>' requested here
    int __ec = _VSTD::__libcpp_thread_create(&__t_, &__thread_proxy<_Gp>, __p.get());
                                                     ^
<source>:26:21: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::thread::thread<void (Executor::*)(Task), Executor *, std::optional<Task>, void>' requested here
        std::thread child_thread {&Executor::executeChild, this, std::move(cur_task)};
                    ^
/opt/compiler-explorer/clang-14.0.0/bin/../include/c++/v1/type_traits:1885:5: note: '~__nat' has been explicitly marked deleted here
    ~__nat() = delete;
    ^
1 error generated.
Compiler returned: 1
```

So clang with libc++ does not really provide a helpful error message, but neither does clang with stdlibc++ nor gcc nor MSVC.